# MonoAndroid folder is missing in Windows

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

The MonoAndroid framework folder is missing in Windows. It is generally present in the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid` I have installed Xamarin Android. why is the folder not being shown?

Comment: make sure the mobile app workload is enabled in setup and also try to repair visual studio

Comment: Please open the Options in your VS, check the setting is correctly like this screenshot.https://imgur.com/a/U2GPYkn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the path of the MonoAndroid folder for the visual studio 2019 is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid`

Under Distributable Code Files for Mobile Development with Xamarin, the path of the MonoAndroid is mentioned in the below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/redistribution

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to accept your answer after two days. It will help others who have similar issue.